# EmberJS cancel (rollback) object with HasMany

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

let's say I have a ParentObject that *hasMany* Items. I want to implement my Cancel feature in my *Add* route that will rollback everything.

In a nutshell, I have :

ParentObject that *IsNew* and *IsDirty*

and potentially...

Items[] that will also be *IsNew* and *IsDirty*

So basically, I simply want to kill those within my NewController...

Here come the faulty code :

```
this.get("items").forEach(function(item)
{
   item.deleteRecord();
});

this.get("model").rollback();

// Some redirection stuff
```

As simple as it may looks, it crashes...

Here's the console output for the crash

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` on <App.ParentObject:ember572:fixture-0> while in state root.deleted.saved. Called with {name: number, oldValue: undefined, originalValue: undefined, value: undefined}.
```

If someone could figure  out what may be faulty and explain what I'm doing wrong, would be pretty appreciated !

EDIT **

I played around with transaction and clearing the relationships with no success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I JUST ran into this. For me it was happening because I had observers in operation when I was performing the rollback. I had to prevent them from firing by adding in a check in the function to check for "model.isDeleted". If it wasn't, I let it through, otherwise prevent it. That seemed to solve it for me.

Comment: Thanks, same issue for me and fixed by checking isDeleted