# performing rollback on model with hasMany relation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have models defined as :

```
App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    layoutName: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    answers: DS.hasMany('answer', {async: true})
});
```

I have a component that allows for deleting and adding answers to question model. The component comes with apply and cancel button and when the user clicks on cancel, I wanted all the changes(adds/deletes of answers) to be reverted. Currently rollback doesn't do the trick, I event tried model.reload() when using rest adapter and that didn't work for me either. Any idea how I can go about doing a rollback in this situation?

When using the rest adapter, I pretty much fall to the issue pointed here : [EmberJS cancel (rollback) object with HasMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852285/emberjs-cancel-rollback-object-with-hasmany)

Thanks, Dee

**UPDATE :**

Since I couldn't perform rollback the intended way, I performed these steps:

```
1) get all the answers back from the server
2) remove answer association from the question
3) manually add answer association to the question model from data received from server
```

This seems to be working well BUT sadly I am getting this one error that I cannot shake off.

Here is a jsbin of updated progress: http://jsbin.com/uWUmUgE/2/

Here you can create new answer and then append it to question and do rollback too. BUT, if you follow these steps, you will see the issue I am facing:

```
1) delete an answer
2) add an answer
3) perform rollback
4) add an answer
```

It throws this error:
**Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` on  while in state root.deleted.uncommitted. Called with {name: position, oldValue: 1, originalValue: 1, value: 2}.**

I will super appreciate any help you can provide.

**WORK-AROUND:**

One simple workaround was to just hide the answers on delete. I modified the model a bit like:

```
App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    layoutName: DS.attr('string'),
    markToDelete: DS.attr('boolean', {default: false})
});
```

And my rollback function had this logic:

```
answers.forEach(function (answer) {
    if(!answer.get('id')){
        //newly created answer models that has not persisted in DB
        question.get('answers').removeObject(answer);
        answer.deleteRecord();
    } else {
        answer.rollback();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of your scope but for this relationship (I'm actually rolling back the belongsTo here but I'm curious if this helps in any way)

```
   App.Appointment = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        customer: DS.belongsTo('customer', {async: true})
    });

    App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        appointments: DS.hasMany('appointment', {async: true})
    });
```

I'm able to rollback both the appointment and it's hasMany customer model like so (from within my route)

```
App.AppointmentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
actions: {
  willTransition: function(transition) {
    var context = this.get('context');
    var dirty =context.get('isDirty');
    var dirtyCustomer=context.get('customer.isDirty');  
    var message = "foo";
    if ((dirty || dirtyCustomer) && confirm(message)) {
        transition.abort();
    }else{
        context.get('customer').get('content').rollback();
        context.rollback();return true;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Hi @Toran thanks for the response. When I try to get context from within my component action that handles the rollback, it returns the component instance itself. What do you get in the context in your case?

Comment: ah, sorry my example is from within a route (I'm yet to do anything w/ a component so I'm not sure how that would be similar/ or not)